# Azure Function V4 Not Logging Startup Errors

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function V4 but experiencing a very odd issue in that upon startup its crashing but failing exactly why its failing to log to app insights. The only entry I get is.

[image]

**host.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            },
            "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
        }
    }
}
```

program.cs

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .AddCommandLine(args)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false)
    .Build();

var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
    {
        var keyVaultName = configuration.GetValue<string>("AzureKeyVault:Name");
        var keyVaultUri = $"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net";

        builder.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri(keyVaultUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
    })
    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
    {
        services.TryAddSingleton<ITelemetryInitializer, TelemetryInitializer>();
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();

        var value = host.Configuration["some-secret"]; // Failing here

    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

If I remove the key vault integration this works. However, this works fine locally but I guess the point is why isn't the failure being logged in app insights? It just says stopping and thats about it, no inkling of the exception.

Comment: As a little trick you can go to the Azure Portal. Open the console for the resource. And from there start your app. E.g. dotnet myapp.dll. That should allow you to see any errors on startup. As for the error it could be related to the credentials, but hard to tell with the limited information.

Comment: I guess my main concern is here is that I know its crashing but its not logging the reason why. Is there a way to log within Program.cs?

Comment: to catch startup errors in Azure Functions that aren't logging to App Insights, wrap startup code in try-catch blocks and log exceptions to the console. Ensure Azure Function's managed identity has correct Key Vault permissions. Verify App Insights is set up with a proper instrumentation key, and check the Azure portal's Function App 'Log stream' for startup errors. Load secrets with error handling in place to prevent silent failures.

Comment: code:`try
{
    var host = new HostBuilder()
        // Configure
        // ...
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            // ... other configurations
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
            services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
            var value = host.Configuration["some-secret"];
        })
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.Error.WriteLine($"Error during startup: {ex.Message}");
    Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    throw;
}
`

Comment: Using the console writeline is how you get the errors to appear in the log stream?

Comment: If you think about how the builder is working: none of the `.Configure` methods take effect until `.Build()` has completed. Your code is throwing the exception _inside_ the service collection builder, therefore before those services (including App Insights) are available.

Comment: You raise a good point though: we have increasingly complex builder patterns in our apps... And yet, often we just assume they'll work fine, so we don't have sufficient logging. A good lesson.

Comment: @AndrewB you are absolutely right this is what I was thinking. In my case it was failing to hit key vault but logging no failures. Wrapping it in a try catch and doing a console write didn't work either in exposing the issue.

Comment: I even tried doing the log stream within Azure but it didn't show anything. Ran the live metrics to see if any exceptions were raised but didn't show anything.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided seems to be having compilation errors.

- `.Build` has been used two times in `Program.cs`.

[image]

- Check if the code is deployed in your Azure Function App.

---

I have created a .NET 8 isolated Azure function and used below code to fetch the secrets from key Vault.

**Program.cs:**

```cs
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWebApplication()
    .ConfigureServices(services =>
    {
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
        services.ConfigureFunctionsApplicationInsights();
    }).ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
    {
        var keyVaultName = "<keyvaultname>";
        var keyVaultUri = $"https://{keyVaultName}.vault.azure.net";

        builder.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri(keyVaultUri), new DefaultAzureCredential());
    })
    .Build();

host.Run();
```

**Function:cs:**

```cs
public class Function1
{
    private readonly ILogger<Function1> _logger;

    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    [Function("Function1")]
    public IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
    {
        var secretName = "<secretname>";
        var secretValue = _configuration.GetValue<string>(secretName);

        _logger.LogInformation($"The value of {secretName} is {secretValue}");

        return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
    }
}
```

**host.json:**

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"

      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
  },
  "functionTimeout": "00:50:00"
}
```

**Console output:**

```cs
[2024-02-14T14:01:22.559Z] Azure Functions .NET Worker (PID: 28632) initialized in debug mode. Waiting for debugger to attach...
[2024-02-14T14:01:22.651Z] Worker process started and initialized.

Functions:

        Function1: [GET,POST] http://localhost:7090/api/Function1

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-02-14T14:01:25.592Z] Executing 'Functions.Function1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=68a4d5c2-9fc0-4810-accf-bc3fba0a762c)
[2024-02-14T14:01:26.760Z] The value of secret1 is 123
[2024-02-14T14:01:26.767Z] Executing OkObjectResult, writing value of type 'System.String'.
[2024-02-14T14:01:26.912Z] Executed 'Functions.Function1' (Succeeded, Id=68a4d5c2-9fc0-4810-accf-bc3fba0a762c, Duration=1370ms)
```

[image]

**Application Insights of function app:**

[image]

Comment: See AndrewB comment in the question I think logging hasn't been configured at this point. You are right there is a typo in the code but if for example you were to read some config that didn't exist or even make it throw an exception it wouldn't log it